# Move Layout to top of screen (with code)

Tags: android, layout

I need some help trying to do the following. I have a vertical linearlayout containing one horizontalscrollview and one "regular" scrollview (first image) with a webview inside. I need to programmatically remove the horizontal one and move the lower one up and/or cover the entire screen (Second image).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0"
        android:layout_weigth="0.6">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button1" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
    <ScrollView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0"
        android:layout_weigth="0.4">
            <WebView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </WebView>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: just make the horizontal scrooll view from visible to gone like view.setVisiblity(View.Gone);

Comment: Tried that. But since i have layout_weight i need to change that too.

Comment: Next you can set weight and height of your scroll view programmatically to make it resize for full screen